# Rarefaction wave is an entropic solution!!

Tags: entropy, hyperbolic-equations

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a strictly convex function.

And $u:\mathbb{R}×[0,+\infty[ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

where $u(x,0)=u_l$ if $x \lt 0$
and $u(x,0)=u_r$ if $x \gt 0$

And consider the conservation law equation:

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f(u)}{\partial x}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $t \gt 0$.

We know that if *u does not satisfy the entropy condition $u_r \lt u_l$, then the rarefaction wave occur*, and it is continuous.

So my question is why are **rarefaction waves** considered as

1)**entropic solutions**
2)**unique**

although the case of **rarefaction waves** came after the solution being **non-entropic**!!

Comment: Your Riemann problem has always a unique entropic solution, which is a shock wave if $u_r < u_l$, and a rarefaction wave in the opposite case.

Comment: @Rigel And how to prove that is has always a unique entropy solution? Plus how can we consider the rarefaction as an entropy, although it came after the condition of entropy is not satisfied! And thanks in advance.

Comment: The entropy condition $u_r<u_l$ in OP follows from the Lax entropy condition for shock waves with convex flux function $f$. Here (see e.g. the book by Dafermos), the entropy solution to the Riemann problem is either an admissible shock wave or a rarefaction wave -- and *there is no other option*. Thus, the entropy solution must be a rarefaction whenever $u_r\geq u_l$.